# Output plain html between @ tag in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

If I have an `if` statement in a cshtml file:

```
<div>
    @if (true)
    {
        @Html.Raw("(True)")
    }
</div>
```

How can I print `"(True)"` to the html? Currently I need to use `Html.Raw` which is unsafe, is there other safer way?

**EDIT:** removed html tags.

Comment: What is wrong with just `@if (true) { <strong>True</strong> }`. And why do you think its unsafe?

Comment: `<strong>True</strong>` just enough there. `Html.Raw` usually used for decode HTML strings returned from certain property inside viewmodel to affect view page.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Supposedly if I don't use any html tag, how can I safely output a string? e.g. a `(True)` string.

Comment: <text>(true)</text>

Comment: `@if (true) { @:(True) }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Razor’s @: and  syntax can then be used for scenarios where you want to avoid using an HTML element within a code container block, and need to more explicitly denote a content region.

Official source:https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax

Hope it will be helpful , kindly let me know your thoughts or feedbacks

Thanks
Karthik

Answer (score 0):

I don't agree with your security assessment of html.raw but you could use this as an alternative:

```
    @if(true)
            {
                <text> (True) </text>
            }
```